# How to run Azure Functions as IoT Edge Module on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: azure, docker, raspberry-pi, azure-functions, azure-iot-edge

I'm looking for someone who was able to follows the documentation of Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-deploy-function) and Jon Gallant (https://blog.jongallant.com/2017/11/azure-iot-edge-raspberrypi/) with success.

After following the whole documentation to get a working Azure Function on a Raspberry PI hosted in a docker container, the Function does not work and the edgeAgent log contains just an info that the Functions can't start. To find out what is happen, I setup the debug environment like described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-vscode-debug-azure-function but nothing works. After hit the last F5 (as its described) I get the error, that the docker container does not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today there is no Azure Functions image for ARM released. If you look at the docker hub url https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azureiotedge-functions-binding/tags/ there are just Windows Nano container and Linux x64 container available.

Comment: okay, thanks... it is what I expected after some tries. Unfortunately the environment does not give a hint also not the documentation. But the Raspberry Pi is one of the most obvious devices which should supported.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Dariusz is right.

So, I went to check the status of Azure Functions Runtime and the good news is that they have now a version of their runtime for ARM. https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/azure-functions-runtime/tags/ for ARM.
So, we just need to update our Binding and start publishing our image for Arm. 
I opened this GitHub Issue to rack the status: 
https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge/issues/485

UPDATE: We have release 1.0.0-preview022 that has ARM version for Function that works for raspberry pi! Let us know if you found any problem. We should be updating our VS Code Template soon.